# Fetch is returning html rather than JSON response

Tags: html, django, fetch-api

I am working on the cs50 web development project Network. Basically building a twitter copycat.

It is still in process but so far I have two fetch requests for a JSON response. Once works perfectly but the other, which is a very similar request, returns html instead of JSON, causing an error. Can't figure out why this one doesn't work. Code snippets below:

Here is the one that is returning html for my profile.html file for some reason. The commented out parts are the actual fetch JSON request but I temporarily changed it to show me in the console what is was returning.
profile.js:

```
function load_posts_profile() {

    console.log("load_posts_profile running");

    document.querySelector('#prof-posts').style.display = 'block';

    fetch(`/profile_posts`)
    //.then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
    //.then(posts => {
        // Print posts
        //console.log(posts);
        //posts.forEach(post => show_posts_profile(post));
    //});

}
```

profile.html:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <!--insert profle name below in h3-->
        <h2 id="profile-name"></h2>
        <br>
        <h4 id="followers"></h4>
        <br>
        <h4 id="following"></h4>

        <!--add js to load user's posts only-->
        <div id="prof-posts">
        </div>

    {% else %}
        <strong> Login To See Profile</strong>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'network/profile.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("all_posts", views.all_posts, name="all_posts"),
    path("<str:poster>", views.profile, name="profile"),
    path("profile_posts", views.profile_posts, name="profile_posts")
]
```

views.py snippet:

```
def all_posts(request):

    posts = Post.objects.all()
    posts = posts.order_by("-timestamp").all()

    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)

def profile_posts(request, poster):

    posts = Post.objects.get(poster=poster)
    posts = posts.order_by("-timestamp").all()

    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)


def profile(request, poster):

    return render(request, "network/profile.html", {
        "poster": poster,
    })
```

And here is the js file with the similar fetch request that works perfectly. Why would this one work(ie return JSON) but the other returns html?:

```
function load_posts() {

    console.log("load_posts running");

    document.querySelector('#all-posts').style.display = 'block';



    fetch(`/all_posts`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
        // Print posts
        console.log(posts);
        posts.forEach(post => show_posts(post));
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When in debug mode django returns an html response when an error occures, usually this is the problem, I think you're passing a parameter poster to the view function but you're not excepting one in the url path

In the future there are a few things to remember, when you get a different response then the one you expected, you should check your logs in the terminal or check the response code in the console client side, if it starts with 5 ot is a server error, of ot Starts with 4 it wasn't found or similar and you should check the logs

Here is how you should modify your code:
Add str:poster to the url path and modify the fetch request to include this in your url

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you mind being more specific in the modification to my code? I'm not sure I understand where/what to add.